# How can find all Labels in one canvas element wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I have canvas with few labels, lines and rectangles. I want to get only Labels from canvas, and then to replace with another labels. Is it possible to get only labels? I try to foreach elements but is give me exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Shapes.Line' to type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Label'.

I try with this code:

```
foreach (System.Windows.Controls.Label child in canvas.Children)
{
    try
    {
        double.Parse(child.Content.ToString());
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        continue;
    }

    canvas.Children.Remove(child);
}
```

Anybody know how can get only labels from canvas.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`Enumerable.OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) :

```
foreach (var child in canvas.Children.OfType<System.Windows.Controls.Label>())
{
}
```

From msdn:

> The OfType(IEnumerable) method returns only those elements in
>   source that can be cast to type TResult.

Comment: thanks...did`nt knew that.

Comment: Note, that this won't find *all* child `Label`s. The result will contain only direct children.

Comment: @Dennis - yes, but the OP's said `I have canvas with few labels, lines and rectangles`, also it's unusual to nest other panels in a `Canvas`

Comment: @w.b: what do you mean - unusual? Canvas is just a `Panel`. It could contain anything. While this is (possible) unusual to you, this can be usual to anybody else (e.g., to me :) ). Anyway, this was just a warning for OP. Logically your code is OK and will filter collection.

Comment: @Dennis - the OP said `I have canvas with few labels, lines and rectangles`, didn't mention other Panels